# Own event for custom UserControl in XAML!

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I want to create an own event (which I'll fire via code) for a CustomControl via XAML.

This would allow me to add a trigger for an animation which I create in XAML.

Comment: How to register a custom event via XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define the events of a control in the xaml, you must do this in code behind, its the same as you cant define members of the control on xaml.